# Editing existing viewmodel data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have searched for days for an answer to this but cant seem to find one that works for me so i apologize if this was answered elsewhere.

I have a

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
```

with a basic structure of

Zone = ID: {} Size:{} Details:{[ State:{} Zipcodes:{[Zipcode: {44444}, Zipcode:         {11111},{..}]}]}

```
function ZoneDetail() {
    var self = this;
    self.ZoneId = ko.observable();
    self.Zipcodes = ko.observableArray();

    self.addZipcode = function () {
        self.Zipcodes.push(new Zipcode());
    };

    self.deleteZipcode = function (zip) {
        self.Zipcodes.remove(zip);
    };

};
```

Now my problem comes with trying to edit the pre-existing data.

The above code works perfect when making new details and adding new lists of zipcodes to those new details. However, If i wanted to delete zipcode 44444 or add another zipcode to the detail 44444 is in it just doesn't do anything with no errors.

```
<input type="button" value="Add Zipcode" data-bind="click: $data.addZipcode"  style="font-size: .9em;" />

<a href='#' data-bind="click: $parent.deleteZipcode">Delete</a>
```

Those are my bindings for the buttons and they work perfectly for new stuff but do nothing and give no errors when editing existing data that came in

Answer (score 1):

You kind of have an unfinished symphony here.  The .addZipcode is pretty easy because you're just taking an input somewhere and adding it to your array of Zipcodes.  To delete, you need a way to identify the Zipcode you want to delete.  I would offer a dropdown list of the current Zipcodes like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.Zipcodes, optionsText: 'value', value: $root.selectedZipcode, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select><br />
<button data-bind="click: $root.deleteZipcode">Delete Selected Zipcode</button>
```

For this to work, your Zipcodes would have to have this data structure:

```
var zipcode = { value: 44444 };
```

Your current array of Zipcodes doesn't make sense to me.  They're objects but the value of the Zipcode itself isn't set to any property name.  Was the structure supposed to be:

```
Zipcodes: [{ Zipcode: 44444 }, { Zipcode: 11111 }, {...}]
```

I'm assuming it would be this way, so substitute accordingly:

```
Zipcodes: [{ value: 44444 }, { value: 11111 }, {...}]
```

The other thing you'd need to do is add the selectedZipcode property to your ViewModel:

```
function ZoneDetail () {
    ...
    self.selectedZipcode = ko.observable();
    ...
    self.deleteZipcode = function () {
        if (self.selectedZipcode()) {
            ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(self.Zipcodes(), selectedZipcode());
            self.selectedZipcode(null);
        }
    };
}
```

---

*Note: I'm not a fan of making function calls or having logic in data-binds.  To me, the only acceptable parameter to anticipate in function references on a data-bind is the current context.  What I mean by this is:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Zipcodes = ko.observableArray([{ value: 44444 }, { value: 11111 }]);
    self.deleteZipcode = function (Zipcode) {
        ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(self.Zipcodes(), Zipcode());
    };
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.Zipcodes">
    <!-- The $data context in this div is each individual Zipcode item.  Any function references in here will be passed the current data context when called -->
    <span data-bind="text: $data.value"></span><br />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.deleteZipcode">Delete This Zipcode</button>
</div>
```

You can do it this way if you want, the difference is that each Zipcode object listing will have its own Delete button, and maybe you only want one button.  So that's more food for thought.

Comment: Ya sorry for my crappy pseudo code i think the biggest thing here is gonna be the $root.Zipcodes and the arrayremoveItem. Also, I cannot use a dropdownlist because all of the zipcodes need to be displayed at the same time and each zipcode has to have its own "delete" button so the <a href='#' data-bind="click: $parent.deleteZipcode">Delete</a> actually sits next to its corresponding zipcode so its a 1-1 ratio delete buttons to zipcode

Comment: Ah, ok.  Then you'd follow my second example after the `<hr />` in my question (after *Note), like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFTPU/)

Comment: Ya that still doesnt work. I really think my problem lies more with the Zipcodes array that comes in from the ko.mapping.fromJS(); Its like the array that gets passed into the viewmodel from there is uneditable or not observable or something.

Comment: If the sample data structure in your question is what gets output then that's where your problem is.  Notice that all of your properties are objects.  ko.mapping.fromJS() will make them all observable values, including the Zipcodes array (it's wrapped in `{}`).  This is what you're trying to map from: `Zipcodes:{[Zipcode: {44444}, Zipcode: {11111},{..}]}`.  Imagine saying, `var foo = {44444};`  That's not a valid object declaration.

Answer (score 0):

the deleteZipCode method is expecting a parameter:

```
self.deleteZipcode = function (zip)
```

You are not passing a zip  to the function on click. try

```
<a href='#' data-bind="click: $parent.deleteZipcode(44444)">Delete</a>
```

or substitute 44444 with the value you want to delete.

Comment: The resulting behavior is not what you might expect.  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExDrz/).  The `deleteItem` function is resolved during the page binding, the returned value, `null`, is what the click binding will call when the button is clicked, so nothing happens. Oddly, the `addItem` button causes the `deleteItem` function to be called since it adds an item to the `foo` array causing KO to update the DOM.  So be careful when calling functions in bindings.  I personally think it should be avoided altogether.